# While converting russian characters to UTF-8, showing `?` for some characters

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I am decoding

`Subject: =?utf-8?B?W0RJXSBSVC1OTi1NVk5POiDQlNC40YDQtdC60YLQvtGA0Lg=?=
 =?utf-8?B?0Y8gL29wdC9lc2xvYWRlci9kYXRhL2ltL3RyYW5zbG9nINC90LUg0LjQt9A=?=
 =?utf-8?B?vNC10L3Rj9C10YLRgdGPINCx0L7Qu9C10LUgMiDRh9Cw0YHQvtCyIC0gT0s=?=`

with mb_convert_encoding and getting

`[DI] RT-NN-MVNO: Директория /opt/esloader/data/im/translog не из? ?еняется более 2 часов - OK`

irrespective of

`[DI] RT-NN-MVNO: Директория /opt/esloader/data/im/translog не изменяется более 2 часов - OK`

Wondering what could be the cause and how to fix it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's the [encoded-words syntax](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2047#section-2), how exactly are you using `mb_convert_encoding()` to decode it?

Comment: Did you try the following? 
mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', 'auto');

Comment: Sounds like the line breaks are slicing a character in half… please show the code which attempts to decode it.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yes

Comment: @Nidhi yep, but no luck

Answer (score 1):

I have used `str_ireplace('=?= =?', '?==?', $string);`

before `mb_convert_encoding()` it works like charm. Seems like line breaks are slicing a character in half.

Thanks anyways.